# What wire to use to extend omlopp ikea lights

Tags: led, wire

I have some [omlopp from Ikea drawer lights](http://www.ikea.com/gb/en/products/lighting/integrated-lighting/omlopp-led-lighting-strip-for-drawers-aluminium-colour-art-00245229/) and the correct transformers, but unfortunately the cable on the lights is pretty short and needs extending for quite a few.

I'm happy enough to break into the wires and extend them (as they have little Molex style connectors on the end that I can't find, there is [another dead question here trying to do the same](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/292238/identify-the-manufacturers-logo-on-the-connector-used-in-ikea-omlopp-led-lights)) but I just need to know the correct wire to use.

The LED lights are 24V, 2W each:

[image]

A link to something I could use on Maplin or screwfix would be great.

Comment: Any cable with same or thicker guage will do.

Comment: 2W is really not much. The cheapest will probably be cheapest speaker cable you can get by metre.

Comment: The cord in the picture looks like 16 gauge SPT cord.

Comment: Shopping advice is off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

In order to keep within CEC (Canadian Electrical Code) rules the smallest wire for use in wiring fixtures is #16.   From the 120VAC source (panel) to the fixture that wire must be a minimum #14 AWG wire....usually NMD copper if wiring is to be completed in dwelling units.

Answer (score 0):

This question has 2 answers. The first is the calculation based on the given data. The second is what does NEC mandate. I cannot answer the first one as I cannot find the formula.

The answer to the second is NEC states that 14AWG wire should be used in this application for distances up to 18 feet.

Comment: Where are you getting the 18' rule from?

Comment: Neither of these applies,  as the wiring between the power supply and the Omlopp lights is low voltage (24V according to the label clearly visible in the photo). The wiring only needs to carry a current of 2W/24V= 1/12 A or less than 100 mA.